# Java 2d Array Comparision

Tags: java, arrays, loops, 2d

Hello I would like to ask question about comparision in 2d array.
I have following 2d array with double parameters in each row. 
I want to compare first 5 row (ie:Period 0) with secont 5 row (ie:Period1) 
I want to compare 
Comparision will be row by row as 1d array I need two 1 d arrays to compare with each other..

Example ;

Period 0 (row 0) vs Period 1 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 0 row 1 vs Period 1 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 0 row 2 vs Period 1 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 0 row 3 vs Period 1 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 0 row 4 vs Period 1 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

---

Then

Period 1 row 0 vs Period 2 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 1 row 1 vs Period 2 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 1 row 2 vs Period 2 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 1 row 3 vs Period 2 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 1 row 4 vs Period 2 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

---

Then

Period 2 row 0 vs Period 3 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 2 row 1 vs Period 3 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 2 row 2 vs Period 3 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 2 row 3 vs Period 3 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

Period 2 row 4 vs Period 3 (row 0,row1,row2,row3,row4)

---

My aim is to get first row of Period 0 then convert it to 1d array, then take first row of Period1 then convert it to 1d array and so on..

The 2d array is as follows;

double[][] myDistributions = new double[][]{

```
        row0 {0.15250886479593964,0.2610516793197853,0.11441768814194446,0.1265241345428162,0.3454976331995246},
        row1 {0.14389124837314887,0.10513281153155449,0.1833462741873425,0.36788054102686596,0.1997491248810186},
Period0 row2 {0.1111207312911868,0.17499901413730568,0.2914581757577288,0.20433331657432438,0.2180887622394655},
        row3 {0.0948730457966342,0.19288720600625753,0.19471332499886804,0.18018001280247228,0.3373464103957629},
        row4 {0.18877271931210932,0.26521449714587747,0.13230019262559328,0.27631809895720494,0.13739449195931552},

        row0 {0.1274517393962726,0.10526928843184565,0.35751329613481436,0.12240396832200726,0.2873617077151316},
        row1 {0.3016290729137225,0.09902028076323677,0.17515717333485062,0.35620664945852193,0.06798682352968743},
Period1 row2 {0.0948730457966342,0.19288720600625753,0.19471332499886804,0.18018001280247228,0.3373464103957629},
        row3 {0.18877271931210932,0.26521449714587747,0.13230019262559328,0.27631809895720494,0.13739449195931552},
        row4 {0.17804585265772793,0.25651982583759037,0.3860867129515085,0.09453797159458521,0.08480963695844175},

        row0 {0.2311120677942418,0.07901250493611567,0.15795189397863776,0.24546018732208122,0.28646334596884354},
        row1 {0.08823944830766299,0.26313933789756516,0.10406419933285384,0.3365866979847223,0.20797031647719286},
Period2 row2 {0.1274517393962726,0.10526928843184565,0.35751329613481436,0.12240396832200726,0.2873617077151316},
        row3 {0.3016290729137225,0.09902028076323677,0.17515717333485062,0.35620664945852193,0.06798682352968743},
        row4 {0.11962680738039468,0.1590225091909952,0.24009305610431117,0.11189649648370673,0.36936113084052996},

        row0 {0.17804585265772793,0.25651982583759037,0.3860867129515085,0.09453797159458521,0.08480963695844175},
        row1 {0.08823944830766299,0.26313933789756516,0.10406419933285384,0.3365866979847223,0.20797031647719286},
Period3 row2 {0.1274517393962726,0.10526928843184565,0.35751329613481436,0.12240396832200726,0.2873617077151316},
        row3 {0.0948730457966342,0.19288720600625753,0.19471332499886804,0.18018001280247228,0.3373464103957629},
        row4 {0.3962773409768214,0.12002724792315751,0.15722439889764284,0.11854502459707339,0.20792598760527947}};
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how you want to compare each row.

Comment: What type of comparison are you trying to achieve (Equal To, Greater Than, Less Than, Within Range, All)?

Comment: Thanks for reply Jacob G., I supposed that first 5 line is my period 0 then second 5 line is my Period 1 then third 5 line is my Period 2 and remained 5 line is my period 3 I have a function which gets 2 1d array as input. So that  firstly  my input for function will be  (period 0 row 0) and (period 1 row 0 )

Comment: you dont need the signature `new double[][]` when you initialized it like that

Comment: Thanks for reply  I have comparision function which gets 2 1d array as input. So that , I will send each 1d array i mean rows to that function 
                          Period0 row0 vs Period1 row0 
            Period0 row0 vs Period1 row1 
     Period0 row0 vs Period1 row2 
     Period0 row0 vs Period1 row3 
     Period0 row0 vs Period1 row4                                              
                                              ---

Comment: Then
                          Period0 row1 vs Period1 row0 
            Period0 row1 vs Period1 row1 
     Period0 row1 vs Period1 row2 
     Period0 row1 vs Period1 row3 
     Period0 row1 vs Period1 row4

Comment: Then 
                          Period0 row2 vs Period1 row0 
            Period0 row2 vs Period1 row1 
     Period0 row2 vs Period1 row2 
     Period0 row2 vs Period1 row3 
     Period0 row2 vs Period1 row4                                              
                                              ---

Comment: *"get first row of Period 0 then convert it to 1d array"* A row *is* a 1d array, so no conversion necessary. Also, it seems you're asking for a `compare(double[] arr1, double[] arr2)` method, presumably to see if they are equal(?), and all the rest of your question is just fluff, is that right? If so, just use [`Arrays.equals(double[] a, double[] a2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-double:A-double:A-). The rest of that fluff is just you writing loops to do what you say. Do you need help writing loops?

Comment: compare(double[] arr1, double[] arr2) but it is not a normal number to numer comparision , i will use js divergence method to get similarity. Again my matrix is 2d i wish to divide it into 4 2d arrays and then i want to get first with second, then second with third then third with fourth

Comment: myMethod(ROW0,ROW5) myMethod(ROW0,ROW6)  myMethod(ROW0,ROW7)
 myMethod(ROW0,ROW8)
 myMethod(ROW0,ROW9)
myMethod(ROW1,ROW5)
 myMethod(ROW1,ROW6)
myMethod(ROW1,ROW7)
myMethod(ROW1,ROW8)
 myMethod(ROW1,ROW9)
     myMethod(ROW2,ROW5)
     myMethod(ROW2,ROW6)
     myMethod(ROW2,ROW7)
     myMethod(ROW2,ROW8)
     myMethod(ROW2,ROW9)
     myMethod(ROW3,ROW5)
     myMethod(ROW3,ROW6)
     myMethod(ROW3,ROW7)
     myMethod(ROW3,ROW8)
     myMethod(ROW3,ROW9)
     myMethod(ROW4,ROW5)
     myMethod(ROW4,ROW6)
 myMethod(ROW4,ROW7)
myMethod(ROW4,ROW8)
     myMethod(ROW4,ROW9)

Comment: Then myMethod(ROW5,ROW10)
myMethod(ROW5,ROW11)
myMethod(ROW5,ROW12)
myMethod(ROW5,ROW13)
myMethod(ROW5,ROW14)
  myMethod(ROW6,ROW10)
  myMethod(ROW6,ROW11)
 myMethod(ROW6,ROW12)
 myMethod(ROW6,ROW13)
 myMethod(ROW6,ROW14)
 myMethod(ROW7,ROW10)
 myMethod(ROW7,ROW11)
 myMethod(ROW7,ROW12)
  myMethod(ROW7,ROW13)
  myMethod(ROW7,ROW14)
  myMethod(ROW8,ROW10)
  myMethod(ROW8,ROW11)
  myMethod(ROW8,ROW12)
  myMethod(ROW8,ROW13)
  myMethod(ROW8,ROW14)
  myMethod(ROW9,ROW10)
  myMethod(ROW9,ROW11)
  myMethod(ROW9,ROW12)
 myMethod(ROW9,ROW13)
myMethod(ROW9,ROW14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've mentioned within one of your comments pretty much what your doing we can ***sort of*** understand what you're trying to accomplish here. To be bluntly honest and with no disrespect by any means, your explanations suck. :P

The way I gather it, you are trying to take the rows from two specific Two Dimensional (2D) double type arrays and retrieve a divergence value from those specific rows of double type data. You of course haven't divulged the type if divergence you're doing so I will have to assume it's a [Kullback–Leibler Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). Either way, you can take the code I have supplied below and modify it to call whatever Java method you desire to gather your required divergence.

In order to carry out this task we're going to need a couple specific methods with the most important one of course being the method that provides us with a divergence. The method I provide below does just that and it was written some time ago by **Charles Sutton** from the Univ. of Massachusetts Amherst, Computer Science Dept. The method is part of "MALLET" ([MAchine Learning for LanguagE Toolkit](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/mallet/)).  Here is the [Mr. Sutton's Divergence method](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ReturnstheKLdivergenceKp1p2.htm) which is OpenSource:

```
/**
* Returns the Kullback–Leibler (KL) Divergence, K(p1 || p2).
*
* The log is w.r.t. base 2. <p>
*
* *Note*: If any value in <tt>p2</tt> is <tt>0.0</tt> then the KL-divergence
* is <tt>infinite</tt>. Limin changes it to zero instead of infinite. 
* 
*/
public static double klDivergence(double[] p1, double[] p2) {
    double log2 = Math.log(2);
    double klDiv = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < p1.length; ++i) {
        if (p1[i] == 0) { continue; }
        if (p2[i] == 0.0) { continue; } // Limin

        klDiv += p1[i] * Math.log( p1[i] / p2[i] );
    }

    return klDiv / log2; // moved this division out of the loop -DM
}
```

For our next method we need a way to take the two supplied 2D double type arrays and pull each row of data out of them so as to retrieve the divergence from those two specific rows whichever they are. The method I provide below (**kldFromDoubleArrays()**) does this. It is as basic as possible so it will be easy to follow:

```
/**
* This method will take each row from the supplied 2D double type array1 and
* each row from the supplied 2D double type array2 and display the 
* Kullback–Leibler Divergence for each of those rows of data processed.<br><br>
* 
* Note: This method outputs its results into the Console Window.<br><br>
*
* Note: This method utilizes <b>Charles Sutton's</b> method named klDivergence() to
* acquire Kullback–Leibler Divergence values.<br><br>
* 
* @param array1 (2D Double Type Array)<br>
* 
* @param nameForArray1 (String) The string name to use for array1 for console 
* display purposes.<br>
* 
* @param array2 (2D Double Type Array)<br>
* 
* @param nameForArray2 (String) The string name to use for array2 for console 
* display purposes.
*/
private void kldFromDoubleArrays(double[][] array1, String nameForArray1, 
        double[][] array2, String nameForArray2) {
    //Iterate through Rows of array1...
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        //Declare a 1D Array to hold current row from array1
        double[] p0 = new double [array1[i].length];

        //Iterate through Columns of current array1 Row...
        for (int j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++) {
            //Place current array1 row into a 1D Array p0
            p0[j] = array1[i][j];

            //Iterate through Rows of array2...
            for (int k = 0; k < array2.length; k++) {
                //Declare a 1D Array to hold current row from array2
                double[] p1 = new double[array2[k].length];

                //Iterate through Columns of current array2 Row...
                for (int l = 0; l < array2[k].length; l++) {
                    //Place current array2 row into a 1D Array p1
                    p1[l] = array2[k][l];

                    //Get the KL Divergence fpr p0 and p1 1D arrays
                    //and display it within the Console window
                    double kld = klDivergence(p0, p1);

                    //Display to Console
                    System.out.println("The Divergence between Row " + i + 
                            " of " + nameForArray1 + " and Row " + k + " of " +
                            nameForArray2 + " is: -->  " + kld);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will be easy for you to modify this method to exactly suit your needs.

As from your original post, I'm assuming that your 2D Arrays are in relation to specific Periods hence period0[][], period1[][], period2[][], and finally period3[][]. Therefore the four 2D double type arrays would be generally structured as:

```
double[][] period0 = {  
        {0.15250886479593964,0.2610516793197853,0.11441768814194446,0.1265241345428162,0.3454976331995246},
        {0.14389124837314887,0.10513281153155449,0.1833462741873425,0.36788054102686596,0.1997491248810186},
        {0.1111207312911868,0.17499901413730568,0.2914581757577288,0.20433331657432438,0.2180887622394655},
        {0.0948730457966342,0.19288720600625753,0.19471332499886804,0.18018001280247228,0.3373464103957629},
        {0.18877271931210932,0.26521449714587747,0.13230019262559328,0.27631809895720494,0.13739449195931552}
        };    

double[][] period1 = {
        {0.1274517393962726,0.10526928843184565,0.35751329613481436,0.12240396832200726,0.2873617077151316},
        {0.3016290729137225,0.09902028076323677,0.17515717333485062,0.35620664945852193,0.06798682352968743},
        {0.0948730457966342,0.19288720600625753,0.19471332499886804,0.18018001280247228,0.3373464103957629},
        {0.18877271931210932,0.26521449714587747,0.13230019262559328,0.27631809895720494,0.13739449195931552},
        {0.17804585265772793,0.25651982583759037,0.3860867129515085,0.09453797159458521,0.08480963695844175}
        };

double[][] period2 = {
        {0.2311120677942418,0.07901250493611567,0.15795189397863776,0.24546018732208122,0.28646334596884354},
        {0.08823944830766299,0.26313933789756516,0.10406419933285384,0.3365866979847223,0.20797031647719286},
        {0.1274517393962726,0.10526928843184565,0.35751329613481436,0.12240396832200726,0.2873617077151316},
        {0.3016290729137225,0.09902028076323677,0.17515717333485062,0.35620664945852193,0.06798682352968743},
        {0.11962680738039468,0.1590225091909952,0.24009305610431117,0.11189649648370673,0.36936113084052996}
        };

double[][] period3 = {
        {0.17804585265772793,0.25651982583759037,0.3860867129515085,0.09453797159458521,0.08480963695844175},
        {0.08823944830766299,0.26313933789756516,0.10406419933285384,0.3365866979847223,0.20797031647719286},
        {0.1274517393962726,0.10526928843184565,0.35751329613481436,0.12240396832200726,0.2873617077151316},
        {0.0948730457966342,0.19288720600625753,0.19471332499886804,0.18018001280247228,0.3373464103957629},
        {0.3962773409768214,0.12002724792315751,0.15722439889764284,0.11854502459707339,0.20792598760527947}
        };
```

Now all we need to do is call our **kldFromDoubleArrays()** method to process the periods you want. In your post you specified that the rows to be processed are:

- Each Row from period0 against each Row of period1;
- Each Row from period1 against each Row of period2;
- Each Row from period2 against each Row of period3;

So, knowing this we will call our method three times:

```
//Create a Underline for Console window display.
String ul = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(100, "=")) + "\n";

//Period0 To Period1 Comparison:
kldFromDoubleArrays(period0, "Period 0", period1, "Period 1");
System.out.println(ul);

//Period1 To Period2 Comparison:
kldFromDoubleArrays(period1, "Period 1", period2, "Period 2");
System.out.println(ul);

//Period2 To Period3 Comparison:
kldFromDoubleArrays(period2, "Period 2", period3, "Period 3");
System.out.println(ul);
```

Here is some sample output:

```
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 1 of Period 1 is: -->  -0.16008580289377392
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 1 of Period 1 is: -->  -0.16008580289377392
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 1 of Period 1 is: -->  -0.16008580289377392
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 1 of Period 1 is: -->  -0.16008580289377392
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 1 of Period 1 is: -->  -0.16008580289377392
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 2 of Period 1 is: -->  0.025341952815786797
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 2 of Period 1 is: -->  0.025341952815786797
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 2 of Period 1 is: -->  0.025341952815786797
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 2 of Period 1 is: -->  0.025341952815786797
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 2 of Period 1 is: -->  0.025341952815786797
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 3 of Period 1 is: -->  -0.08495427575998642
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 3 of Period 1 is: -->  -0.08495427575998642
The Divergence between Row 2 of Period 0 and Row 3 of Period 1 is: -->  -0.08495427575998642
```

And that about wraps it up. I hope this has helped you somewhat. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you :) ı m using that mallet method but i have a question my periods are dynamic i may have hundreds of period so i can not create period like this

Comment: That's is indeed odd....because I didn't create them...you did in your initial post. It really doesn't matter since you can pass whatever 2D double type arrays you like to the **kldFromDoubleArrays()** method as long as they both contain the same number of columns in both arrays. What it sounds like you need is assistance with creating either 1D or 2D Arrays from specific double type data you are receiving...I'm not sure because at this point I'm still confused at what your real requirements are. To help you further I will need to see some real data and exactly what you want to do with it.

Comment: Is the data you want to process coming in as a steady stream and you need live divergence as it is received? Or, is it coming in as a data file? I don't know...just guessing here now.

Comment: I m filling this matrix from database , I just made here a sample . I m using topic modeling in mallet and I have 5 topic for each period I mean in above matrix first 5 row refers period 0 first row of period 0 refers Topic 0, second topic 1 and etc.. then same topics for period 1 and go on

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to say here. So, your pulling this data in from a database table (or tables) using some SQL query and now you need to place the result set from that query into 2D Double Type Arrays with each Array consisting of 5 Rows (topics) and 5 Columns holding topic data. Each array of [5][5] is considered a Period. Divergence is required from each new Period Topic rows and a previous Period Topic rows. Correct? I think I just went cross-eyed. I need to see how your retrieving data from database to create the 2D Arrays.

Comment: Or at least whatever it is you stored that database data into. Array, ArrayList, data file, etc

Comment: Yeah, i put records as i want to 2d array, i just need to iteratation in arrays. I send an email to you to check.. And i copied a source code to my answer.And also in sample i just have 5 columns for each row, I have hundreds of column in my matrix.  Each array of [5][hundreds of columns]

Comment: I put all records to Array list then converting it to 2d array as I mentioned above                                                                                                               
          int nCol = rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
   while( rset.next()) {
       String[] row = new String[nCol];
       for( int iCol = 1; iCol <= nCol; iCol++ ){
               Object obj = rset.getObject( iCol );
               row[iCol-1] = (obj == null) ?null:obj.toString();
       }
       table.add( row );
   }

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
int numOfTopicsInEachPeriod=5;

double[][] myFirstRow=new  double [numOfTopicsInEachPeriod][myDistributions[0].length];
double[][] mySecondRow=new double[numOfTopicsInEachPeriod][myDistributions[0].length];


int count =0;
int counter =0;
int temp=0;

for(int j =0;j<myDistributions.length-numOfTopicsInEachPeriod;j++){

   int mod=j%numOfTopicsInEachPeriod;
   int countOfTopics = j/numOfTopicsInEachPeriod;
   count=0;

   if(mod==0){
       temp=1;
       count=numOfTopicsInEachPeriod* countOfTopics; 

   }

   if(temp==1&&mod!=0){count=numOfTopicsInEachPeriod* countOfTopics; }

     for(int i=counter;i<numOfTopicsInEachPeriod;i++){

       myFirstRow[i]=myDistributions[count];
       mySecondRow[i]=myDistributions[count+5];

       System.out.print("myFunction(Row["+j+"],Row ["+(count+5)+"]),"+"\t" );

       count++;

   }

   System.out.println();
}
```